# Can't see line based SCM blame infomation in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, perforce, blame

I am currently trying SCM blame feature in latest (5.1.2) SonarQube. My problem is that retrieved blame shows only latest commit for entire file. This mean that one user is responsible for entire file. According to [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/SCM+Activity+Plugin) it should be possible to have SCM info line-based - Each line with commit ID, Date and user.

[image]

We are using Perforce for SCM.

In TeamCity, it is set as maven build step with flowing parameters:

```
-Dsonar.jdbc.url=%system.sonar.staging.jdbc.url%
-Dsonar.jdbc.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
-Dsonar.jdbc.dialect=postgresql
-Dsonar.jdbc.username=%system.sonar.staging.jdbc.username%
-Dsonar.jdbc.password=%system.sonar.staging.jdbc.password%
-Dsonar.host.url=%system.sonar.staging.host.url%
-Dsonar.scm.forceReloadAll=true
-Dsonar.perforce.port=%vcsroot.port%
-Dsonar.perforce.username=%vcsroot.user%
-Dsonar.perforce.password.secured=%vcsroot.user%
-Dsonar.scm.provider=perforce
-Dsonar.perforce.clientName=%env.P4Workaround%
-Dmaven.scm.perforce.clientspec.name=%env.P4Workaround%d%
```

Do I need to adjust something or this might be bug in SonarQube?

Comment: Since you're using Perforce as your SCM, why not use Time-Lapse View?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But my intention is to present results on web UI without needing to open client, connect to server, looking for file and so on. According to the documentation it should be possible, it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of SonarQube Perforce plugin you are using. This issue should have been fixed in version 1.2. But you may have to analyze project from scratch to see the changes (delete project in UI then do a new analysis).

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Our version was 1.1 - Thanks for help!

Comment: Can someone please look into below issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010513/sonarqube-line-based-scm-blame-information-where-its-stored